# Adding existing XCode project to new project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

This is possibly an extension of

> [How can I add an existing project as a working copy in XCode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301572/how-can-i-add-an-existing-project-as-a-working-copy-in-xcode-4)

I have an existing iOS XCode project 'Project A' with one target, which is the app it builds.

Now I have another project 'Project B' I am currently working on and would like to add the 1st project as is to this one as and include it as a feature.

When I drag the .xcodeproj file of A, I can see the project come in, however, it brings in the target as well. When I look at the 'Target Membership' of any file in A, it has A's target and I don't see B's target.

What I would like to do is only have B's target and link all files in A to B.

I tried creating a lib out of A but that process is far more tedious. I would really like to proceed down the copy+link path. Can someone suggest what can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be more interested in an [Xcode Workspace](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH7-SW1), unless you are truly interested in merging these two projects for good.

If you want to bring in all of the source files of the other project, you can right click the project in Xcode and choose "Add files to 'MyProject' ..." and in the interface that is presented you can choose target membership. I would go this route to "merge" the projects together rather than dragging in the full Xcode project.

There very well may be a way to do it how you are hoping, but this is the route I know and would take.